# I do not know why I get the following error:uninitialized constant Games Object.const_get(camel_cased_word) ^

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, routes, controller, namespaces, uninitialized-constant

I work on a Rails project and I seem to have a route or controller problem which I do not understand. This is the error I receive: uninitialized constant Games Object.const_get(camel_cased_word) ^^^^^^^^^^ raise MissingController.new(error.message, error.name) ^^^^^. This are my routes:
` Rails.application.routes.draw do
cccc devise_for :users

```
  namespace :games do
    resources :hangman, only: [:index]
  end

  get 'hangman/guess', to: 'hangman#guess'

  root to: "pages#home"
end`
```

This is my controller:
`    class HangmanController < ApplicationController
def index
@secret_word = "hangman"
end

```
  def guess
    secret_word = "hangman"
    incorrect_guesses = 0
    render json: { secret_word: secret_word, incorrect_guesses: incorrect_guesses }
  end
end`
```

This is my model:
    `class Hangman < ApplicationRecord belongs_to :user end`

This is my index file:
`<div id="hangman-game" data-controller="hangman"> <h1>Hangman Game</h1> <div> <p>Secret Word: <span data-target="hangman.secretWord"></span></p> <p>Incorrect Guesses: <span data-target="hangman.incorrectGuesses"></span></p> <p>Guesses Remaining: <span data-target="hangman.guessesRemaining"></span></p> </div> <div> <input type="text" data-target="hangman.guessInput" placeholder="Enter a letter"> <button data-action="click->hangman#guess">Guess</button> </div> </div>`

I do not see why I have an error here. I used namespaces for once, I wanted to create different games in the app folder. So I used this path: app/games/hangman/models or views or controllers and their content. What do I do wrong? Thank you for your help and sorry in advance for all this code.

I expected my code to show but I cannot open the page at localhost/games/hangman...